# Envelope-Distort a vector shape in fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks

Is there a way to envelope-distort a vector shape in Adobe Fireworks? Meaning - distort it by by manipulating the object's surrounding rectangle.
I want to reach effects like wave or fish-eye.

Photoshop has a similar tool, but for bitmaps...

[image: The equivalent in Photoshop to what I'm looking for]

Answer (score 1):

If it's a vector shape, simply add anchors and alter the shape.

Fireworks does not provide any "warp" or distort features beyond the standard Modify > Transform > Distort. And that feature is restricted to essentially independent corner movement, no arcing or curves.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator can do all kinds of crazy things with Warp. Maybe Warp in Illustrator, then paste the resulting path into Fireworks?

I do the same with Illustrator and Photoshop quite often, which gives you the best of both worlds: advanced vector tools, including distortion and warping, but also great pixel-based design and bitmap layer effects. It's a win-win, provided you own both apps.